# Database: faster to dump in list or query everytime?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a program to handle sales and inventory of businesses (of all dimensions) and I've made it so every time it interacts with the data stored in the database a function is called for that specific query. I believe this is inefficient since accessing a database is often a slow process, and as the software functions right now, these queries for small I/O operations in the db are made very often. So I've been thinking of a way to improve this.

I thought about dumping the data of different tables in different lists at the beginning of the software execution and using those lists through its functioning. Then, at close, make the corresponding changes in the database according to those made in the lists. This seems a better solution since all the data would be in memory and the slow process of handling big amounts of data (to which db frameworks are optimized) would be at the execution and exiting of the program.

As an example the following function I call to retrieve an entire table or an entire column of a table:

```
def sqGenericSelect(table, fetchCol=None):
'''
table: table retrieved. If this is the only argument provided, the entire table gets retrieved.
fetchCol: fetched column. If provided, the function returns only the column passed here.
'''
try:
    with conn:
        if not fetchCol: fetchCol = '*'
        c.execute(f'SELECT {fetchCol} FROM {table} ')
        return c.fetchall()
except Exception as exc:
    autolog(f'Problem in table: {table}', exc) #This function is for logs
```

(And it gets called 8 times!)

Is this the right approach? If not, how should I improve this?

Comment: I'd recommend experimenting with both approaches and profiling.  The overheads for using sqlite are not the same as for using an RDBMS like MS-SQL etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, im actually not a native english speaker and im not sure what are you refering to when you say "profiling". You mean measuring the time it takes to both aproaches to acomplish a specific task?

Comment: Yes, that's right - Python provides some [tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/debug.html) for this

Comment: This could help:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database